# exception thrown if user property retrieved

Tags: my-site, user-profile-property

I'm retrieving different custom and default user properties from the my sites profile in a webpart.

The Problem is, if i'm trying to retrieve profile information which hasn't been set yet the webpart throws a System.NullReferenceException.

How can i check if the property is set to work around that problem?

Comment: please post some code, or we cant help you.

Comment: Here is the code where the exception is thrown: `result = u[property].Value.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (properties["MyProperty"] != null) { ...` ?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Debugger jumps not in the if-clause.. don't know why :/ Looks like this:`if (u[property] == null)
                {
                    result = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = u[property].Value.ToString();
                }`